# How to navigate a XML object in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, loops

I have a regular xml object created from a response of a web service.

I need to get some specific values from some specific keys... for example:

```
<tag>
 <tag2>
  <tag3>
   <needThisValue>3</needThisValue>
   <tag4>
    <needThisValue2>some text</needThisValue2>
   </tag4>
  </tag3>
 </tag2>
</tag>
```

How can I get `<needThisValue>` and `<needThisValue2>`  in Ruby?

Comment: Are you sure that is what you want? Do you mean `<needThisValue>3</needThisValue>` and `<needThisValue2>some text</needThisValue2>`? Or, do you mean `3` and `some text`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a big fan of [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org):

```
xml = <<EOT
<tag>
 <tag2>
  <tag3>
   <needThisValue>3</needThisValue>
   <tag4>
    <needThisValue2>some text</needThisValue2>
   </tag4>
  </tag3>
 </tag2>
</tag>
EOT
```

This creates a document for parsing:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
```

Use `at` to find the first node matching the accessor:

```
doc.at('needThisValue2').class # => Nokogiri::XML::Element
```

Or `search` to find all nodes matching the accessor as a NodeSet, which acts like an Array:

```
doc.search('needThisValue2').class # => Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
doc.search('needThisValue2')[0].class # => Nokogiri::XML::Element
```

This uses a CSS accessor to locate the first instance of each node:

```
doc.at('needThisValue').text # => "3"
doc.at('needThisValue2').text # => "some text"
```

Again with the NodeSet using CSS:

```
doc.search('needThisValue')[0].text # => "3"
doc.search('needThisValue2')[0].text # => "some text"
```

You can use XPath accessors instead of CSS if you want:

```
doc.at('//needThisValue').text # => "3"
doc.search('//needThisValue2').first.text # => "some text"
```

Go through [the tutorials](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials) to get a jumpstart. It's very powerful and quite easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

```
require "rexml/document"
include REXML
doc = Document.new string
puts XPath.first(doc, "//tag/tag2/tag3/needThisValue").text
puts XPath.first(doc, "//tag/tag2/tag3/tag4/needThisValue2").text
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this Nokogiri tutorial](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html).
You'll need to install nokogiri gem.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `Nokogiri` gem. You can read some tutorials [enter link description here](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html). It's fast and simple.